# How to solve slowly importing CSV to sqlite database when sqlite more larger file?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, file-upload

I have doubt after I try a PHP script that importing CSV file to sqlite database and when database size bigger. Then next files that was upload will using more and long time to execute and upload.

It may be take up to 300 seconds to upload next CSV file that contain 1,000 rows only if sqlite database bigger than 30,000 kb size or more. And with this long time, a web server will stop and terminate this uploading page to 500 or 504 bad gateway.

I don’t know had any solution to solved this kind of an issue?

Comment: I'm confused.  Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I need a solution to solved long time uploading when sqlite database bigger or larger size. I just doubt why page loading time is using much more seconds when override or adding data to sqlite.